# Azure environment variables only available inside server.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, azure-devops

Trying to setup React app deployed by Azure Devops to use environment variables from Azure.

The command run to start the application is

`pm2 start server.js`

Within server.js I have added some logging...

`console.log(process.env);`

This dumps out all the env variables as you would expect (including those set in Azure).

When I attempt to use the same environment variables elsewhere, they are undefined.  The files I'm attempting to access the environment variables are in typescript files, and I'm attempting to access them using  `process.env.MY_VAR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run a process in the context of a build or release, it has access to the environment variables that are defined in the build/release. If you run it elsewhere, it doesn't. Because it's a different environment, and nothing is setting those environment variables. If you want those environment variables set, you need to set them.

In an Azure app service, the correct place is in the App Settings section of your app service. You can use an ARM template to deploy your app service and configure the app settings, or you can set the app settings directly while deploying with the App Service Deploy task.